# Generate the MS word document in django

Tags: python, django, python-docx

Currently i am generating the reports in pdf format. But now i want to generate the reports in ms word or docx format.

my api.py file

```
def export_pdf(request,id):
        report = Report.objects.get(id=id)                

        options1 = ReportPropertyOption.objects.filter(report=report,is_active=True)   
        locations = []  
        out_string = ""    
        map = None



        for option in options1:  
            option.property = get_property_name(option.property)        
            option.exterior_images = ReportExteriorImages.objects.filter(report = option)  
            option.interior_images = ReportInteriorImages.objects.filter(report = option)
            option.floorplan_images = ReportFloorPlanImages.objects.filter(report = option)
            option.fitouts =    ReportFitOut.objects.filter(propertyoption = option)   
            if (option.gps_longitude):

                locations.append("&markers=color:red|label:S|"+""+str(option.gps_longitude)+","+str(option.gps_latidtude)+"")
        for loc in locations:
            out_string+=loc

        if locations:
            map = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Bangalore&zoom=12&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap"+out_string+"&sensor=true"              
        #map = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&center=\\"
        html  = render_to_string('report/export.html', { 'pagesize' : 'A4', }, context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'options1':options1,'meta':report.meta,'map':map}))

        result = StringIO.StringIO()       
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), dest=result, link_callback=fetch_resources )        
        #pdf = Docx(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), dest=result, link_callback=fetch_resources )
        if not pdf.err:
            return result
        else:
            return None
```

I am getting all the data in result and then exporting that data to pdf. But now i want to export the data to the docx or MS word format. The same result i want to export to docx format.
As i am getting the data in pdf format so i dont want to convert that exported pdf to docx. I want to export directly in docx.
I tried using python-docx, but not able to figure out how to export out in docx format.
Can anyone guide me how to this. Which modul i should use in django.
Please help me

Comment: You should use `python-docx` to export to `docx` format. There is no Django built-in for handling this. Another option would be py2docx (https://github.com/rafaels88/py2docx).

Comment: yes i know ,  i tried that also, but i am getting error on pdf =Document(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), dest=result, link_callback=fetch_resources ) this line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I generate a docx file from within a Django view:

```
from docx import *
from docx.shared import Inches

def TestDocument(request):

    document = Document()
    docx_title="TEST_DOCUMENT.docx"
    # ---- Cover Letter ----
    document.add_picture((r'%s/static/images/my-header.png' % (settings.PROJECT_PATH)), width=Inches(4))
    document.add_paragraph()
    document.add_paragraph("%s" % date.today().strftime('%B %d, %Y'))

    document.add_paragraph('Dear Sir or Madam:')
    document.add_paragraph('We are pleased to help you with your widgets.')
    document.add_paragraph('Please feel free to contact me for any additional information.')
    document.add_paragraph('I look forward to assisting you in this project.')

    document.add_paragraph()
    document.add_paragraph('Best regards,')
    document.add_paragraph('Acme Specialist 1]')
    document.add_page_break()

    # Prepare document for download        
    # -----------------------------
    f = StringIO()
    document.save(f)
    length = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(
        f.getvalue(),
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + docx_title
    response['Content-Length'] = length
    return response
```