# Getting a word document from a django generated view

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, ms-word

I have a class based django view that presents some tables and text to the user dependent on their inputs.

I would like to have a button on this page that allows the user to download this data as a word document.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

urls.py

```
app_name = "patient"
urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', views.PatientAddView.as_view(), name="patient_add"),
    path(
        route='<patient_id>/',
        view=views.TreatmentTemplateView.as_view(),
        name='treatment_detail'),

]
```

views.py

```
class TreatmentTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "../templates/patient/treatment_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["patient_id"] = self.kwargs["patient_id"]
        result = find_treatment(context["patient_id"])
        context = result[0]
        context["patient"] = result[1]

        return context
```

hmtl

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<!-- {% block title %}Patient: {{ patient.name }}{% endblock %} -->
{% block content %}

<h3>Patient Summary</h3>
<p>
    {{pt_letter|linebreaks}}
</p>
<br>
<br>

<h3>Current Medication</h3>
<p>
    {{current_med_letter|safe}}
</p>

<br>
<br>

<h3>Past Medication</h3>
<p>
    {{past_med_letter|safe}}
</p>

<br>
<br>
<h3>Plan </h3>
<br>

<h5>Treatment Recommendation</h5>
<p>
    {{newmed_letter|safe}}
    {{existingmed_letter|safe}}
</p>
<br>
<h5>Physical Health Monitoring</h5>
<p>
    {{monitor_letter|safe}}
</p>
<br>
<h5>Potential Drug Interactions</h5>
<p>
    {{interaction_letter|safe}}
</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: check this library https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: also this for use in django https://stackoverflow.com/a/24122313/7887883